# Запись в файл Python

Tags: python, файлы

Программа спрашивает у пользователя какой-то текст и заносит его в текстовый файл, добавив перед этим сегодняшнюю дату и время. Если в файле уже есть текст, новый нужно дописывать, не удаляя старый. Записи разделены пустой строкой.

Чего не хватает в этом коде?

```
from datetime import datetime
vremja = str(datetime.today())
tekst = input("Введите запись: ")
f = open("dnevnik.txt", "a", encoding="UTF-8")
f.write(vremja + "\n")
f.write(tekst + "\n")
f.write("\n")
f.close
```

Comment: Кроме забытых скобок на последней строчке всё вроде норм

Comment: Спасибо, потерянные скобки добавила, но файл все равно пуст :(

Comment: Увы, у меня не пуст и всё работает)

Comment: Спасибо большое! Проверила еще раз, действительно, все работает!

Answer (score 1):

На python 3.5 все работает. Вы файл в той же директории ожидаете?

Comment: Да. Спасибо, все работает! Проблема оказалась в потерянных скобках в последней строке.